# Останавливается скачивание файла с сайта PHP

Tags: php, html, файловая-система, zip

Есть сайт на котором при нажатии на кнопку скачать, архивируется файл, который пользователь хочет скачать, только когда нажимаешь на кнопку, файл скачивается, но в браузере приходится нажимать возобновить загрузку и после этого всё нормально. С интернетом всё хорошо. Как это пофиксить?

```
$filename = "";
$project_name = "";
$filename = "";
$FORM['filename'] = "";
$FORM['project_name'] = "";

if (isset($_POST['filename'])) $FORM['filename'] = htmlspecialchars($_POST['filename']);
if (isset($_POST['project_name'])) $FORM['project_name'] = htmlspecialchars($_POST['project_name']);

$filename_path = '../'.$FORM['filename'].'.zip';
$filename = '../'.$FORM['filename'];
$project_name = $FORM['project_name'];

Zip($filename,$filename_path);

function Zip($source, $destination) {

    if (!extension_loaded('zip') || !file_exists($source)) {
        return false;
}

$zip = new ZipArchive();
if (!$zip->open($destination, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)) {
    return false;
}

$source = str_replace('\\', '/', realpath($source));

if (is_dir($source) === true)
{
    $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($source), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

    foreach ($files as $file)
    {
        $file = str_replace('\\', '/', $file);

        // Ignore "." and ".." folders
        if( in_array(substr($file, strrpos($file, '/')+1), array('.', '..')) )
            continue;

        if (is_dir($file) === true)
        {
            $zip->addEmptyDir(str_replace($source . '/', '', $file . '/'));
        }
        else if (is_file($file) === true)
        {
            $zip->addFromString(str_replace($source . '/', '', $file), file_get_contents($file));
        }
    }
}
else if (is_file($source) === true)
{
    $zip->addFromString(basename($source), file_get_contents($source));
}

return $zip->close();
}
```

Comment: 1. У вас уязвимость. В `$FORM['filename']` можно вставить а-ля `../config.php` и будет скачан конфиг сайта. 2. Случаем не отваливается по таймауту? `ini_get('max_execution_time');` в студию. 3. Решение хорошее, но я бы отдавал предварительно подготовленный файл с диска, если так можно сделать. Залил проект, запустил скрипт архивирования, получил готовый zip, его и раздавать.

Comment: @Total Pusher, ini_get выдаёт 500, так как уже менял значение max_execution_time в php.ini. Суть в том, что нужно нажать на кнопку, заархивировать файл, пользователь его скачает и удалить его, что бы не занимал место. Но суть в том, что после нажатия загрузка останавливается и приходиться нажимать 'возобновить загрузку'

Comment: 1. Откройте хром, вкладка сеть, нажмите на "скачать". Появится адрес. Из контекстного меню выберите `copy as curl`. Добавьте параметр --verbose и запустите в консоли. Что выдает?